# Docker procedure - treat local copy as staging server?

Tags: docker

I've read a bit about docker and have read only about the following procedure:

1. Build container using Dockerfile
2. Push container to repo/server
3. Run container
4. new version, go to step 1)

The claim is that this is quick, which it sometimes is.  However, often in these recipes, I'll see a 'git pull' or 'add ' step followed by a bundle install or some other preparation step.  If you always do this, you throw away a fair amount of progress and start the processes as if you had never installed your app in the first place, though it won't have to reinstall any prerequisites.  Not to mention, you have to upload a bunch of big images to your server - much of which is duplicate stuff anyway.

It occurs to me that a better procedure might be to treat your local Docker instance as a staging server, ssh-ing in (to get magical SSH user agent forwarding to work more reliably), updating code, testing, then committing the changes and pushing it up to whatever cloud service runs your docker instances.

Am I missing something?  Is this what everyone actually does, but doesn't really write about (because it's more complex)?  Or have I just not stumbled on to the article that talks about this?

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers generally follow the "golden image" rule - if you need to update it, you create a new image.

Because Docker caches the intermediate results of building Dockerfiles, subsequent builds tend to be fast. Also, the building of images tends to be automated (e.g. see automated builds on the Docker Hub), so as long as it doesn't take a really long time, it's not a problem.

You *really* don't want to be making changes to to containers manually as you will lose track of the changes and become unable to recreate them.

Comment: I'm deploying a rails application, which involves a ton of gems, mixed between public and private repositories.  To build such an image from a recipe is technically challenging (as SSH-agent-forwarding is not quite ready on Macs) quite time consuming (many minutes), and extremely time consuming to push to the cloud (GBs), because of the way that gems are compiled, stored, and used.  It just seems simpler to iterate on the image itself with new code, because bundler & co. won't make it harder than it needs to be in that case.

Comment: That will work; you could have an entrypoint script that gets the code etc when the container starts. But why can't you build the images in the cloud?

Comment: I'm struggling with SSH keys and permissions - I don't want to add any keys of any kind into the dockers, not even read-only ones (because I shouldn't have to!).  I could build them on a cloud VPS, but I can't squeeze the whole build process into a Dockerfile, because they don't seem to support any kind of SSH key forwarding.

Comment: Yeah keys and secrets are a problem. I have seen some people use environment variables to store them; that way they never end up in version control.